# Confine div replacement function to parent div

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to replace one child div with another on the click of a link. I have a 'working' draft (https://jsfiddle.net/graemebryson/bttuapq7/), but I'm not sure how to confine the function to only affect the parent div. As it stands, clicking the link makes all divs change as they share the same class names.

How can I ensure the function only affects the parent div? I've tried this (https://jsfiddle.net/graemebryson/eqqj3sjp/1/) but it seems to break it entirely (code pasted below).

My logic here is probably pretty wild too, so any feedback would be massively appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** Solved, with a far better solution, thanks to @JoshCrozier - working here: https://jsfiddle.net/9w4v1wqn/

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="one-half first content-flip">

<div class="box-overview">
  <h5>Item 1 Overview</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <a id="show-details" class="btn">Show details</a>
</div>

<div class="box-detail" style="display:none;">
  <h5>Item 1 Details</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <a id="hide-details" class="btn">Hide details</a>
</div>

</div>

<div class="one-half content-flip">

<div class="box-overview">
  <h5>Item 2 Overview</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <a id="show-details" class="btn">Show details</a>
</div>

<div class="box-detail" style="display:none;">
  <h5>Item 2 Details</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <a id="hide-details" class="btn">Hide details</a>
</div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#show-details").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".box-overview").hide();
    $(this).closest(".box-detail").fadeIn();
  });

  $("#hide-details").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".box-detail").hide();
    $(this).closest(".box-overview").fadeIn();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in order to get a reference to the element that the `click` event occurred on. In the snippet below, `this` refers to `.show-details` or `.hide-details`.

The [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to traverse the DOM in order to select the ancestor `.box-overview` or `.box-detail` element(s). You will also notice that I chained the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)/[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) methods in order to select the corresponding siblings in order to fade them in/out.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j4znah74/)

```
$(".show-details").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".box-overview").hide().next(".box-detail").fadeIn();
});

$(".hide-details").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".box-detail").hide().prev(".box-overview").fadeIn();
});
```

As a side note, an `id` is suppose to be unique within a document. Since you were duplicating `id` attribute values, the event listeners weren't being attached to multiple elements with the same `id`s. I simply changed `#show-details`/`#hide-details` to classes instead.

---

As a side note, you can condense your code to the following:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9w4v1wqn/)

```
$(".toggle-visibility").on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggle().siblings().fadeToggle();
});
```

This is similar to the snippet above, except instead of having dedicated `.show-details`/`.hide-details` element(s), there is a `.toggle-visibility` element that will show or hide the corresponding element. The [`.toggle()` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is used to toggle the visibility of the element (it's used in place of `.show()`/`.hide()`). Then the [`.fadeToggle()` method](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) is used in place of `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed the `id` issue. Thanks again for your help Josh, that's bang on.